# Why doesn't fail-safe iterator throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator

And in what situations should the iterator be designed as fail fast in Java? Any insights? Thanks.

Comment: Because this how the language was designed.

Comment: In CopyOnWriteArrayList, the doc says "Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove, set, and add) are not supported. These methods throw UnsupportedOperationException.". why these operations are not supported? Because it made a copy of the underlying array, it shouldn't have any thread safety problem. Is my understanding right?

Comment: what exactly is your question then? in your comment you are talking on something quite irrelevant.  I will strongly suggest you make your question clear and to point

Answer (score 1):

Fail-safe means that the iterator will only fail if the timing was just right in that it would cause data corruption.  This doesn't mean that you won't get away with it sometimes.  In other words, if your code is doing something wrong it may or may not get an exception.  This is in contrast to fail-fast which always throws an exception when you do the wrong thing.

Iterators were likely made fail-safe because the fail-safe implementation is faster (requires less time in synchronized code) and since iterators are used in many places in the Java code, performance is an issue.